# React Native: Not smooth scrolling with DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

## Current Behavior

My code:

```
class App extends Component {
   render() {
    return <Drawer /> {/* rigid scrolling effect */} 
    return <Stack /> {/* smooth scrolling effect if I comment above return statement */} 
  }
}

const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Feed: { screen: Feed }
})

const Stack = StackNavigator({
  Feed: { screen: Feed }
})
```

And Feed component's render is just a bunch of lines:

```
render() {
   return <View style={{flex:1}}>
   <ScrollView>
    <Text>random line...</Text>
   // .. more lines to make it scrollable
   </ScrollView>
   </View>
}
```

## Expected Behavior

The expected behavior is to get smooth scrolling effect in both cases. However, DrawerNavigator screen's scrolling effect is extremely rigid. When I swipe my finger quickly from up to down, it doesn't keep scrolling smoothly automatically like it should in Stacknavigator example.

## How to reproduce

Create App.js file above and create a simple Feed.js component which has a bunch of lines to make ScrollView work.

Can anybody help?

**Update:** Live demonstration: https://snack.expo.io/Hk8Np7nPG

Comment: if i comment  setTimeout function it works perfectly...
are u wanting Stacknavigator came every in 5 sec smoothly ?

Comment: @Man it works without settimeout just because it doesn't switch to drawer view then

Comment: ok then u want switch Stacknavigator in every 5 sec smoothly!!!! right?

Comment: @Man No! Read the question. I'm switching every 5 second so that you can scroll and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
render() {    
        return (
              <View style={{flex:1}}>    
                <ScrollView>
                  <View>
                    {Your Contnet}
                  </View>    
                </ScrollView>    
              </View>
         )}
```

it is worked for me...
hope it'll also worked for you

Comment: does not work for me. the motion is still very jerky

Comment: have you tested on Real device?
 @mehulmpt

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [**NativeBase**](https://nativebase.io/) with standard tabs Container and Contet (like ScrollView ) Header and...

first try :

```
npm install native-base --save
```

then:

```
npm i
react-native link
```

and here is your full example code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Content , View , Text } from 'native-base'; //don't need import 'react-native' components

export default class GeneralExample extends Component {
render() {    
    return (
          <Content >    
              <View>
                {Your Contnet}
              </View>    
          </Content>
     )}
}
```

and if you wanna change the speed just **ScrollView** try:

```
<ScrollView decelerationRate={0.5}>
   <View/>
</ScrollView>
```

in NativeBase Use [THIS LINK](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/357)

Comment: Hi. I'm actually using nativebase only. But the code scroll is still jerky with content as well as scrollview

Comment: @mehulmpt try this code: `<ScrollView decelerationRate={0.5}>

</ScrollView>` I edited in **answer**

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Check updated question for live demonstration